# Problems with using code program

Tags: prolog

Does it work on your machines?
I don't know how to use it- i get errors every time. Tell me please how to use it....

Link to source: http://ai-programming.com/prolog_bot_tutorial.htm

Code:

```
% Program Name: chatterbot1
% Description: this is a very basic example of a chatterbot program
%
% Author: Gonzales Cenelia
% Date: 7 august 2009
%
response_database([
    ['I HEARD YOU!'],
    ['SO, YOU ARE TALKING TO ME.'],
    ['CONTINUE, IM LISTENING.'],
    ['VERY INTERESTING CONVERSATION.'],
    ['TELL ME MORE...']]).
    
select(0, [H|T], H).
select(N, [H|T], L) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, select(N1, T, L).

quit_session(X):- X = 'bye', 
    nl, write('IT WAS NICE TALKING TO YOU USER, SEE YOU NEXT TIME!').
    
write_string([H|T]):- write(H).

chatterbot1:- 
    repeat,
    nl, write('>'),
    read_string(Input),
    response_database(ListOfResponse),
    IndexOfResponse is integer(random * 5),
    select(IndexOfResponse, ListOfResponse, Response),
    write_string(Response),
    quit_session(Input).
```

I have tried some ways to write, maybe i dont know how correctly do it thats errors:

> 1 ?- hi.
>
> ERROR: toplevel: Undefined
> procedure: hi/0 (DWIM could not
> correct goal)
>
> 2 ?- [hi].
>
> ERROR:
> source_sink `hi' does not exist true.
>
> 3 ?- 'hi'.
>
> ERROR: toplevel: Undefined
> procedure: hi/0 (DWIM could not
> correct goal)
>
> 4 ?- ['hi'].
>
> ERROR:
> source_sink `hi' does not exist true.

Comment: @Bart: Done, do you see what's wrong by my or code side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that your code is in a Prolog dialect that's slightly different from SWI Prolog, which you're using. You can try something like this:

```
response_database([
    ['I HEARD YOU!'],
    ['SO, YOU ARE TALKING TO ME.'],
    ['CONTINUE, IM LISTENING.'],
    ['VERY INTERESTING CONVERSATION.'],
    ['TELL ME MORE...']]).

select(0, [H|_], H).
select(N, [_|T], L) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, select(N1, T, L).

quit_session(X):- X = 'bye',
    nl, write('IT WAS NICE TALKING TO YOU USER, SEE YOU NEXT TIME!').

write_string([H|_]):- write(H).

chatterbot1:-
    repeat,
    nl, write('>'),
    read(Input),
    response_database(ListOfResponse),
    IndexOfResponse is integer(random(5)),
    select(IndexOfResponse, ListOfResponse, Response),
    write(Response),
    quit_session(Input).
```

As said by the others, make sure you compile the code and then run it like:

```
chatterbot1.
```

Then it will ask you for some input. Type something like

```
hi.
```

And see a response. 
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Great. Btw, I changed some of the H and T variables to _ to avoid Singleton warnings, in case you were wondering. Have a look here for an explanation: http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/SingletonVar.html

Comment: So if I will make the same changes : write_string -> write, and read_string -> read in the second implementation of chatterbot called chatterbot2 (in given link) so it should work good? -> im gonna check it in a minute...

Comment: So if something doesn't have matter in predicate than we can replace that value by _ what means 'anything' .
What about chatterbot2?

Comment: @Tom: If you check my code for the random function, you see that I already fixed this the first time around. Second, inputting a full sentence with spaces like that will cause your second error. Put it in single quotes. Third, don't modify your question or keep actively asking things after accepting an answer. If you encounter a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: @Bart: ok, sorry Im new... ; i'll Ask new question, and call previous here... random - ok '()'

Answer (score 0):

Before chatting, you need to start the program. For this you type:

```
chatterbot1.
```

Then you should see the prompt of the program:

```
>
```

Now you can chat with the program.

Comment: 3 ?- chatterbot1.

>
ERROR: chatterbot1/0: Undefined procedure: read_string/1

Comment: There are many differing Prolog dialects in use, and apparently some of them know `read_string/1` and some others don't. Try to find some code that implements `read_string/1` for your Prolog implementation.

Comment: Hm what i see in Barts' implementation is changing write_string to write, and read_string to read and it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

you should first compile the program and then run chatterbot1.
something like:

```
>[the program's name].
>chatterbot1.
```

btw read_string/1 is not a default predicate in my prolog dialect (swi-prolog) so I cannot test it.
dunno about yours

Comment: I have SWI-PROLOG too, should i use other programm?
which one does support that predicate as default?-have any ideas?